# Cabal - how to install specific version of package

Tags: haskell, cabal

I need for example a minor version of a package, for example persistent-postgresql .. or hdbc-mysql or whatever.

If I run

```
cabal install persistent-postgresql
```

it will install persistent-postgresql version 1.3 and then I get the error 'At least the following dependencies are missing: persistent-postgresql >= 1.2 && < 1.3'
That's why I would like to install an earlier version of this package to make it work. Or maybe there is another solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For questions like these, you can start by looking at `cabal --help`, or more specifically `cabal install --help`. In this case, you wouldn't even have had to scan through all the options, because the short 'Examples' section at the end shows how to install a specific version.

Comment: It might have shown example for that, but it is not the case any more: there is no example for the --constraint option, and the format is not obvious.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should probably try to cabal install the package that actually depends on `persistent-postgresql` as cabal will then try to select the right version automatically.

However if you do need to do this, a simple way is:

```
cabal install persistent-postgresql-1.2.1.3
```

Or more complicated:

```
cabal install persistent-postgresql --constraint 'persistent-postgresql < 1.3'
```

Here you can just keep specifying that you want something earlier than a particular version as things don't work without needing to know the exact next version down. You can also place constraints on other packages if necessary.